# Mostrar o tanto de combinações possíveis

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {

    int x=10;
    int y;
    int numero;

    printf("quantos digitos tem sua senha: ");
    scanf("%d", &numero);

    y = numero * x;

    printf("sua senha tem %d combinacoes possiveis!", y);


}
```

Por enquanto cheguei nisso, eu preciso fazer um programa q o usuário coloque quantos dígitos tem sua senha e o programa calcule as combinações possíveis com base nos tantos de dígitos q o usuário colocar.

Lembrando que a senha é composta somente por números.

Exemplo: o usuário coloca o valor 1, o programa devera dizer q existe 10 combinações (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9).

Comment: E qual sua dúvida?

Comment: Sua dúvida é sobre combinações ou sobre como aplicar as combinações no código? Se for a segunda opção, qual a parte não está conseguindo aplicar?

Comment: Se os algarismos puderem se repetir na senha então você poderá ter 10^x possibilidades. Se não podem ocorrer repetições então você poderá ter 10! / (10-x)! possibilidades (arranjo simples da matemática).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>    

void main() {

        int y, numero;

        printf("quantos digitos tem sua senha: ");
        scanf("%d", &numero);

        y = pow(10,numero); //elevando 10 (0,1,2...8,9) pela quantidade de numeros

        printf("sua senha tem %d combinacoes possiveis!", y);


    }
```

Não esquecendo de incluir `#include <math.h>` para utilizar a função `pow()`

Comment: obrigado meu brother, deu certinho. abraços

Comment: Valeu Bro, se puder marcar a resposta como correta, eu agradeceria!